# libgthread not up-to-date when running qemu emulator

Tags: macos, pebble-sdk

I'm trying to run the Pebble emulator for the first time with one of my Pebble apps, and I'm getting the following message:

```
$ pebble install --emulator aplite
Couldn't launch emulator:
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/sarbogast/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-3.3/Pebble/common/qemu/qemu-system-arm_Darwin_x86_64
Reason: Incompatible library version: qemu-system-arm_Darwin_x86_64 requires version 4401.0.0 or later, but libgthread-2.0.0.dylib provides version 4201.0.0
```

So it seems that libgthread is too old. How should I upgrade it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command solved my problem:

```
brew update && brew upgrade glib
```

Comment: This works for me! Maybe also do `brew upgrade boost-python` and `brew upgrade pixman` since these were the [emulator dependence packages](https://developer.pebble.com/sdk/install/mac/).